# Proper configuration of /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: raspbian, networking, debian

I'm trying to make my Raspberry Pi into Wifi access point, where the internet connection is provided by Android device attached to it. I'm trying to achieve this by mildly configuring [this guide](https://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/), and I expect to make it work by configuring /etc/network/interfaces, and now it looks like this:

```
auto lo

allow-hotplug wlan0
allow-hotplug eth0
allow-hotplug usb0

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.250.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0

iface wlan0 inet static
 address 192.168.250.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0

iface usb0 inet dhcp
```

Target is to make it work as sort of router creating local network on addresses 192.168.250.x, making my raspberry the .1 device, pc the .2 and allocate other devices connected to access point to next ip's. How should I edit this file to properly make it work?

Comment: The tutorial you have linked is nearly 6 years old. You should consider to use a newer one. At a glance on your interface configuration: you cannot have the same ip address 192.168.250.1 for interface **eth0** and **wlan0**. Every interface must have a unique ip address.

Comment: @Ingo what is the cause of it? I suppose that IP address is just a way to locate given device in given network, so why is it wrong to have the same one on two interfaces? Like routers - accessible by default via 192.168.0.1 on both ethernet and wireless connection?

Comment: Using unique ip addresses is defined by [IP addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address). Just routers need different ip addresses on its interfaces otherwise it cannot distinguish between the subnets it is connected to and it cannot route packets between them.